# Problems with vs code unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

My VS Code showing 3k problems and TMPro problem was solve for a minute [after regenerates project files] but after that error is coming again and this time public is also underline red. I think problem was with that 3k errors in problem window. Please help me anybody.

[image]

Comment: Try re-imporing TMPro

Answer (score 0):

You could try to update the Visual Studio Code Editor package in the unity package manager, to do so, go to window > package manager > change the All Packages to In Project, then select the Visual Studio Code Editor package and update it.

Comment: I also update vs code as well it is not working.

Comment: @sumit you might try Assets> Reimport all

Comment: Showing problem for UI and TextMeshPro

Comment: Can you specify the error or that problem you’re talking about?

Comment: Same error shown in above picture